# Create a group or set of textboxes(edit text) in android application?

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I have some 8 text boxes(edit text) in my layout. How do I add them as a group instead of adding them individually.

I want to take input from user in those textboxes(edit text). Input is related, so I need a group of textboxes. Checked the documentation but didn't find.
Any way to add such textboxes as a group?

Comment: Use a list of text boxes?

Comment: What is the functionality you are trying to achieve as a group?

Comment: @ jungleboy Take input from users. the input is related. So, I' looking for a group of textboxes. Couldn'tfind it in the documentation.

Comment: yes @ByzantineFailure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EditTexts in a Layout (typically a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout will do).
That container will act as a group.

Comment: Can we use radiobuttons for taking input from user?

Comment: If the input is "checked/unchecked", yes. If you meant EditTexts, no. I understood your were talking of TextViews. TextViews aren't editable, while EditTexts are.

Comment: Saying "textboxes" generated confusion.